# Scripts do not work in my ASP.NET Core view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Scripts in view do not work for me. But at the same time scripts work in `_Layout`. For example, if I add a button to `_Layout`, the script works, but in the same view the same button does not work.

I tried to do it through

```
@section Scripts { code... }

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

but it doesn't work at all in both `_Layout` and view

**Update :**

Where it is highlighted in yellow, this button is located in `_Layout`, and where it is red, it is located in View. Yellow invokes the script without issue. And red does not cause

[image]

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Are you getting errors? Are the scripts rendering?

Comment: It only works if the function call button is placed in _Layout.
But it doesn't work if the same button is placed in the View

Comment: Please share your relevant js function, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better. And please make sure your use correct jQuery selector to select the button. Besides, please check if you put and run js function in a partial view.

Comment: Please make sure the value of id attribute is unique within the DOM.

Comment: Thank you. I didn’t know what to give a unique id. I apologize for the stupidity

Comment: Hi @Betsq9, please check my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the value of `id` attribute must be unique within the DOM, you can specify different value for these two cart button, like below.

```
<button id="btnCrt1">Cart</button>

<button id="btnCrt2">Cart</button>
```

Then use following selector to select/match element(s) that have the `id` attribute with a value beginning exactly with `btnCrt`.

```
$("button[id^='btnCrt']").click(function () {
    //code logic here
})
```